# PostgreSQL Stock Update Trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have 2 tables in PostgreSQL: **lines**(*idlines,iditems,quantity*) and **items**(*iditems,stock*). *iditems* is a foreign key in **lines**.
I need a trigger that updates the *stock* field from the **items** table when a new row is inserted in the **lines**. It should replace *stock* with stock=stock-quantity.

I don't have a lot of experience with PostgreSQL but here is what I've done. Unfortunately is not working.

```
DROP FUNCTION function() CASCADE ;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $trigger$
    BEGIN
      UPDATE items SET
      stock=COALESCE(stock,0)-lines.quantity
        WHERE lines.iditems=items.iditems;
        END;


CREATE TRIGGER trigger
    AFTER INSERT ON lines
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE function();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the row in a row trigger use [`NEW` and `OLD`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html):

> `NEW`
>   Data type `RECORD`; variable holding the new database row for `INSERT`/`UPDATE` operations in row-level triggers. This variable is `NULL` in statement-level triggers and for `DELETE` operations.
>
> `OLD`
>   Data type `RECORD`; variable holding the old database row for `UPDATE`/`DELETE` operations in row-level triggers. This variable is `NULL` in statement-level triggers and for `INSERT` operations.

You probably want to use `NEW` instead of `lines` and return the new row:

```
UPDATE items
SET stock = COALESCE(stock, 0) - NEW.quantity
WHERE items.iditems = NEW.iditems;
return NEW;
```

You'll also need to properly terminate your function definition:

```
-- ...
END;
$trigger$ language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger
-- ...
```

You might also run into problems by using the reserved words `trigger` and `function` as your trigger and function names (respectively), I'd recommend better names or at least double quoting them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but before I can try NEW, I need to deal with the following error: <<unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near $trigger$>>.

Comment: @miraco: Check my update, you weren't properly closing your function definition.

Comment: There's also a potential problem with the function and the trigger name, if these are the original ones.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to do one more thing: use "RETURN NEW;" after the WHERE clause. After I used NEW and terminate the function properly, it worked. The names I used in the example were not the original ones.

Comment: @miraco: I just added the `return NEW` for completeness. That's what I get for debugging stuff by eye :)